# MySQLdb Inside Eclipse osx

Tags: python, mysql, django, eclipse, mysql-python

So, after a frustrating weekend, I Finnally got django and MySQL all working fine under 10.8 Thanks everyone for the help, but Now, inside Eclipse, I can't get MySQLdb to work.
I'm getting an

Unresolved import: MySQLdb

inside Eclipse, even though python import MySQLdb works just fine from command line.
I'm fairly new to Eclipse under OSX, sure it's an easy one, but all related ??s seem to be related to the hell of geting these just Installed correctly.

Any of that make sense?

(Also, Auto Config is what I first used to set up pydev, with no luck)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Go to the Preferences - PyDev - Interpreter - Python

Select the python interpreter in the pane

From the Upper Box first remove

Select Auto Config

Finally Accept

Update:

Try adding the egg depending on your module version to your eclipse python path

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4c1

Comment: sorry, that is another part of what I should have said in the post (editing now) Auto Config IS giving me this error, is there a specific file I should be looking for to add to Pydev's directories ?

Comment: adding the egg didn't quite work at first, but added higher level dir than egg and got it working! (Also, re-start Eclipse)  Thanks!